# Why the function can't return the correct answer?

Tags: python

I try to verify the impact of the Variable parameter of the function. here I defined the function test:

```
t = ["test"]
def test(x):
    return x.append("test")
print(test(t))
```

The resulte is None.

And I change this function to the following style:

```
 def test(x):
   x.append("test")
   return x
print(test(t))
```

This time the function give the correct result ['test', 'test'].

So I want to know what's the different about the two function styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `append` method doesn't return anything. It just modifies the list.